# Bidirectional Synchronization of Mysql databases

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, web-applications

I have an issue with regards to database synchronization.

Here is my case:
I will set up my web application in two Tomcat servers. Behind of which there is a Load Balancer. Each tomcat has its own mysql.

The problem is that **if Tomcat_1 is down the traffic will be redirected at Tomcat_2 but if user makes a change at Mysql_2 this change won't be reflected at Mysql_1**.

As you can tell, I can not set up a master-slave replication. Because they both are primary databases.

Is there anyway how to realise this scenario? I can't seem to find a proper solution even though this use case seems too ubiquitous.

Thank you !

Comment: You can setup a multi-master replication. But, why not using a single database instead?

Comment: Hello @acm thank you for replying ! Well I have considered having only one database but what will happen if it crashes ? Probably I will also have to set up a load balancer for the databases itself. 

Do you have any idea on that ? I mean we have ensure high availability for our app. Thanks

Comment: Well, there are many solutions for your use case. You can setup a multi-master replication but write only to one database, while the other works as slave (backup). If it fails you can switch to your backup database using your DB load balancer or whatever solution that works best for you. That's simpler than what you are trying IMO and very effective in practice.

Comment: Yes but my problem with this approach is: what if a user gets registered on the slave database  ? Then the data wont be replicated, and when the master is up and running the user will try to login in that database but his credentials are stored at the slave database. 
Master-slave would be simpler but I am afraid of the above use case . @acm

Comment: You never write to a slave, your apps connect only to one database (M). That database is replicating to other database (B). If M fails your apps will connect to B via load balancer in your case. When M recovers it will automatically resync with B, and you are exactly as you started. It is a master-master replication but it will be transparent to your apps as they will connect to a single DB server.

Comment: @acm what if the user will have to make a write when the (M) is down ? Since it cannot write to a slave what will happen in this case ?
Thankss

Comment: Please read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-solutions-switch.html). An architecture like that is what I'm talking about, just using a different failover mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, I will read it. Will it be difficult to implement, since I will connect them with 2 Tomcat web servers ? Will it take longer than 2-3 days. Thanks @acm

Comment: It is not difficult to implement but the time it will take depends on your skills. I don't think it will take you longer than 2-3 days, though.

Comment: I will have to do it on localhost since I have only one machine, is it okay ? I mean I will just change the ports of my servers. 
Thank you ! @acm

Comment: The benefits of two instances in the same machine to achieve high availability are very limited, besides you would be wasting resources. I wouldn't waste time in configuration having a single machine.

Comment: Well this is for a school project , my choices are limited, or probably I could set up a LAN in virtual box ? Thank you !

Comment: For school project do it the way it is easier for you. Virtual Machine or two local instances.